# Is there a pattern for an algorithm to update Order field in the database in a drag-and-drop UI feature?

Tags: jquery, algorithm, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a html page with a drag and drop JQuery implemented feature, see example from link below, where I allow the user to order the elements.

[Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)

When the div is released a JQuery Ajax callback is send to the server in order to update the integer Order Field in the database. I just have one problem: I don't see a way to do this and I refuse to update the whole database Order field just for updating the order of 2 elements...

I believe this is a very common problem, I would like to know if there is already an algorithm in place to solve it...

thanks all

Comment: If you have a relational system setup where no two items `should` have the same `integer` under the `order field`, then that's an inherit flaw in the design. Your best bet is to iterate over the elements on drop, create a JSON string that has each element and it's position (however you prefer to reference that element), and then have a database abstraction layer already created to handle this method.

Comment: Hey, take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383343/ajax-jquery-html-table-re-order